# charm fails to create charm store client

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, juju

I have created a charm by following the details here @ https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/tools-charm-tools

I created one charm called "foo"

```
$ charm create foo
INFO: Using default charm template (reactive-python). To select a different template, use the -t option.
INFO: Generating charm for foo in ./foo
INFO: No foo in apt cache; creating an empty charm instead.
Cloning into '/tmp/tmpytr_hB'...
remote: Counting objects: 27, done.
remote: Total 27 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 27
Unpacking objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Which is empty and has nothing. that is ok.
Now when I try to list this charm using `charm list`, it gives me below `ERROR`

```
$ charm list
ERROR cannot create the charm store client: cannot load the cookie jar
```

The same error I am getting for few other charm options. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Hi, tried to respond to your comment on your AskUbuntu question, but it was deleted as I did so. Glad you figured out the solution.

Comment: @Arronical, Thanks for your time, the problem is that the error message is not quite helpful there.

Comment: FYI: I filed a bug to display a better error message: https://github.com/juju/charmstore-client/issues/109

Comment: @jrwren thanks. That will be really helpful for the others.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening because my user does not have the root access.

Without `sudo`:

```
$ charm list
ERROR cannot create the charm store client: cannot load the cookie jar
```

With `sudo`:

```
$ sudo charm list
No charms found.
```

All other charm options are also accessible.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a permissions issue in your home directory. You should never need to use `sudo` with juju, charm, or any charm-tools command. Please try to first run `chown -R $USER.$USER $HOME/.local/share/juju` then try again.

Comment: Probably you forgot to tell me to do the same with `$HOME/.go-cookies`. Now i don't have to use `sudo` anymore. Thanks!